# Is there a way to suppress certain types of errors going to Sentry from Airflow?

Tags: airflow, sentry

I'm using the sentry-airflow integration described here:

- https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/guides/airflow/
- https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/logging-monitoring/errors.html

This integration seems to send all error messages to Sentry, and you can't use the typical tricks of defining a `before_send` handler to drop certain errors.

The issue is that I want all errors to propagate successfully through Airflow, so I can use the `on_success_callback`  and `on_failure_callback`, but I don't want certain types of errors to show up in Sentry (i.e., DB connection errors).

Is there a way to do this natively with the Airflow-Sentry integration, or have people built custom message handling to deal with this?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?